# Запятая после "соответственно"

Tags: пунктуация

Соответственно() те, кто это сделают - получат приз.

Ставится ли запятая в таких случаях? Если да, то почему?

Дополнительный вопрос:

Можно ли вместо тире поставить запятую перед "получат"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: "Соответственно, те, кто это сделают, получат приз".

Для постановки тире в таком предложении нет никаких оснований - ни смысловых, ни интонационных, если считать, что ничего ненормативного у нас  не должно быть в принципе, а авторские знаки - это не произвольное отступление от нормы, а нечто более осмысленное.

Тире ставится в предложении "Кто это сделает - получит приз", причем на правах обязательного, а не авторского знака, так как здесь пропущено местоимение "тот".

Comment: Тире ставится в месте пропуска, а не где попало: в начале пропущено "тот", поэтому ближе к концу ставим тире? Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на правило: я такого не нашла.

Comment: Ссылаюсь на грамматику.Придаточное предложение с союзным словом может стоять на первом месте, например: "Кто смел, тот уверен в себе". Соответственно: "Кто смел - уверен  в себе".

Comment: Спасибо. В общем-то да, с запятой "Кто смел, уверен в себе" теряет смысл и выглядит как незаконченный ряд однородных. Но о "Кто это сделает, получит приз" этого не скажешь. Еще поищу информацию.

Comment: Вот нашла у Розенталя о разговорных конструкциях: Запятая ставится внутри конструкций, эквивалентных сложноподчиненным предложениям с отсутствующим соотносительным словом: Кто записаны, получат билеты получше; У кого детей нет, редко дачу снимают; Кто приехал, у нас ночевать будут; Кто с ней занималась, у неё принимала экзамен.

Comment: Предложения, конечно, выглядят как просторечные, но всё равно хорошо, что вы их нашли.И тогда дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на эту тему, а заодно на согласование подлежащего "кто" со сказуемым.

Comment: Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация (раздел 21, п. 6).
Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке (§ 187, п. 2).
Книги можно скачать здесь: http://www.media-school.com.ua/p/blog-page_12.html

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая после **соответственно** нужна. Что касается запятой перед **получат**, то тут тоже можно поставить запятую. Вот пример: тот, кто знает тебя, должен осознавать, что ты хороший человек.

Answer (score 1):

*Соответственно, те, кто это сделают, получат приз.*

Здесь наречие *соответственно* употреблено в функции вводного слова в значении *вывод* (= следовательно). Запятая нужна.

Перед *получат* запятая не возможна, а необходима даже при наличии интонационного тире: *Соответственно, те, кто это сделают, - получат приз.* Главное предложение - *те получат приз*.

В современных СМИ возможна ненормативная постановка тире ВМЕСТО запятой. Но не в данном случае, так как это нарушило бы симметричность знаков (запятых, выделяющих придаточное) и отнесло бы "получат приз" к "кто это сделает", а не к "те". Ср.: *Соответственно, кто это сделает - получит приз.*

Comment: В придаточном предложении глагол в данном случае должен стоять в единственном числе (кто это сделает)

Comment: Соответственно,те,кто это сделает,получат приз. 

Вы про это?

Comment: Глагол может стоять в любом числе. Розенталь: При подлежащем – относительном местоимении "кто" (в функции союзного слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа, например: Те, кто не успел к двери, кинулись в радостной панике к окнам (Макаренко); В полку служат теперь те, кто десять лет назад были пионерами, бегали в школу, играли в снежки (Б. Полевой).

Answer (score 0):

Уберите "соответственно"! Это же кошмар. Понятно, что от контекста многое зависит, но все же.